# Conditional sign up for internal Django site

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using Django (with python-social-auth) to authenticate users for an internal student information system.
We currently have an external SQL table, that keeps track of whether a user is: an admin, staff member, or student, based on their Google Apps email address.

Current post_save function

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_student_or_staff(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            state = UserState.objects.get(
                email=instance.email
            )
        except UserState.DoesNotExist:
            # if exception is raised here, user is not created but site crashes
            # if no exception is raised, a user is created but no admin, staff or student instance
            pass
        if state.staff:
            if state.is_admin:
                Admin.objects.create(
                    user=instance
                )
            else:
                Staff.objects.create(
                    user=instance
                )
        else:
            class_instance = None
            if state.year and state.band and state.set:
                class_model = apps.get_model('class_groups.ClassGroup')
                class_instance = class_model.objects.get(
                    year=state.year,
                    band=state.band,
                    set=state.set
                )
            Student.objects.create(
                user=instance,
                class_group=class_instance
            )
```

When a user first attempts to login, I want to be able to check against that database to see if they meet any of the criteria.
Currently, using the post_save signal for the user (I've also tried to use pre_save but no dice) to somehow halt the creation of a Django user object if they are not on the UserState table.

Is this possible at all? The only way I can halt the creation of a user instance currently is by raising an exception during the post_save, which isn't ideal of course.

Sorry for the broad question, if you need any specifics please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think a more logical place to do this would be in a custom authentication backend. I'm guessing you are using `RemoteUserBackend`? You could subclass it to suit your needs and add it to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your settings.

Comment: Ended up adding a new pipeline for the social-auth backends, thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0):

The best option i think is use the [user_pass_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) function or use the [UserPassTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) for class base views.

Comment: Ended up going with a custom pipeline for social-auth, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding a new pipeline for python-social that checks if the incoming email address is already in the UserState database.
Pipeline added after the social details are retrieved.

settings.py

```
# adding all the pipelines in for the time being, can adjust later
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    # custom pipeline
    'sis_users.pipeline.user_state_exists',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    ...
)
```

pipeline.py

```
def user_state_exists(backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    email = details['email']
    try:
        UserState.objects.get(
            email=email
        )
    except UserState.DoesNotExist:
        raise UserStateDoesNotExistException(backend)
```

exceptions.py

```
from social_core.exceptions import AuthException

class UserStateDoesNotExistException(AuthException):
    def __str__(self):
        return "You must be an administrator, staff member or a student to sign in. Please contact the school for more assistance."
```

Thanks for all the suggestions!